# Rails - How do I create a checkbox that will render a different form when checked without refreshing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

As the title suggests, I am wondering how to create a checkbox on a view that will change what form is rendered without refreshing the page.

In my `app/views/home/` folder I have `_form_1.html.erb` and `_form_2.html.erb`.

I want to default to `<%= render 'form_1' %>` when the box is not checked, and change to `<%= render 'form_2' %>` when the box is checked.

I've attempted to look up how to do this, but things like `.is(":checked")` and `check_box_tag` don't seem to be working for me, or I'm using them wrong.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I am using Rails 3.2.12 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: That the form will change without a refresh (ie. a new request to the server) implies some form of Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do this is to render both the form partials from another view, and put each of them in a div.  The default form div should be visible, and the optional form div should be hidden.  Then you can toggle the display of the divs with a click action on the checkbox.

Depending on what's in the forms and how they interact with your controller, there's likely a lot of other work involved in processing, but in order to toggle the displayed forms, the method above is one option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without a refresh you'll have to use javascript. What you'd do is render each form but as `hidden`. This next part is really easy with jquery. When a checkobox is selected you'd just do something like `$('#form1').show()`, and conversely `$('#form2').hide()`

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm new to putting javascript into the HTML.

Comment: if you created the controller with a rails generator then you probably have a `.js.coffee` file in your `app/assets/javascripts/`. In this file put your jquery. Also, make sure that the page has loaded before you try to bind a click event to your checkboxes. You should probably do a 5 minute tutorial on jquery to get you up to speed. Otherwise you might be a little confused by what I'm talking about but it's easy to pickup.